# INtegral card readers have drivers installed but do not show on my computer

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sd-card, card-reader

I recenlty fixed a computer powerbutton and accidentally unplugged a sd card reader and did not know where was at (didnt knw if it was usb or firewire/ after i found out, i guess i installed it on a different usb so reinstalled the drivers..Drivers show installed successfully, ready to use. but THey do not show up on my computer as removable disks (E:) etc.a s they should I have windows 7 home premium 64 bits. the computer is a Acer Aspire M1201-be50001a. I tried following the installation and they show up while installing and then hide again. Any help is appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Folder Options, there's a setting for "Hide Empty Drives"

Comment: thankss, i did not know that. will try that.. However, they do not appear when I put in my sd card either? :S